# Problems with adding to an ArrayList and then removing the elements

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm sorry if this has been asked before somewhere, but I really haven't seen anything that helps with the exact question that I have. This is for school work, but I've beat myself up for 2 days over trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong, so if someone can help I would more than appreciate it.

I have a program that is basically supposed to enter the name of two sales people, show a table of their potential earnings, and finally compare the differences in their sales. I'm doing this in NetBeans IDE, and I've got all sorts of things in here trying to figure it out.

Everything works fine until I try to pull anything out of my ArrayLists. I was thinking it should be possible to store something in there, then pull it back out to do the math I need to do but I must be doing something wrong. Here's the specific Class code I'm having problems with:

```
class EarningDifference {

  SalesPerson persons = new SalesPerson(); //Access to SalesPerson class
  AnnualSales aSaleC = new AnnualSales(); //Access to AnnualSales class
  ArrayList<SalesPerson> list = new ArrayList<>(); //Access to SalesPerson ArrayList
  ArrayList<AnnualSales> aSales = new ArrayList<>(); //Access to AnnualSales ArrayList

  AnnualSales person1EarningStr; //Person one earnings from AnnualSales ArrayList
  AnnualSales person2EarningStr; //Person two earnings from AnnualSales ArrayList
  Double person1Earning; //Person one earnings as double
  Double person2Earning; //Person two earnings as double
  String person1; //String for person one full name
  String person2; //String for person two full name
  Double difference; //Variable to store the difference between Person1 and Person2 sales
  double totalSales; //variable for Total sales

public void people() {
    person1 = list.get(0).getFirstName() + " " + list.get(0).getLastName();
    person2 = list.get(1).getFirstName() + " " + list.get(1).getLastName();
    System.out.println("Comparing " + person1 + " with " + person2 + ".");
}

void settotalSales(Double totalSales) {
    this.totalSales = totalSales;

        AnnualSales person1EarningStr = aSales.get(0);
        AnnualSales person2EarningStr = aSales.get(1);

    double person1Earning = person1EarningStr.doubleValue();
    double person2Earning = person2EarningStr.doubleValue();

    if (aSales.size() < 2) {
        System.out.println("Need another person to compare");
    } else if (person1Earning > person2Earning) {
        difference = person1Earning - person2Earning;
        System.out.println(person1 + " has earned " + difference + " more in sales than " + person2 + ".");
    } else {
        difference = person2Earning - person1Earning;
        System.out.println(person2 + " has earned " + difference + " more in sales than " + person1 + ".");
    }
}
```

}

Here is the class where items are added to the AnnualSales ArrayList:

```
public class  SalaryTotal {

        double fixedSalary; //Variable for the fixed salary amount
        double commission; //Variable for the comission
        double minimumSales; //Variable to define the minimum amount of annual sales sales persn must make to receive compensation
        double maximumSales; //Variable to define the number after which commission increases
        double advanceRate; //Variable used to define the rate at which compensation increases after minimum sales are met
        double compensation; //Variable for the amount of compensation based on sales
        double totalSalary; //Variable for the total salary
        double totalSales;
        Double compensationD;

        SalesPerson persons = new SalesPerson();
        ArrayList<SalesPerson> list = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Double> aSales = new ArrayList<>();

    public void getCompensation(double totalSales) {

            commission = .21; //The constant commission rate
            minimumSales = 120000; //The constant minimum sales needed to receive compensation
            maximumSales = 150000; //The constant maximum amount above which commission increases by the advanceRate
            advanceRate = 1.67; //The constant at which compensation increasea after minimum sales

                this.totalSales = totalSales;

                if (totalSales < minimumSales) {
                    compensation = 0; //sets compensation to 0 if minimum sales are not met  
                } else if (totalSales <= 150000){
                    compensation = totalSales * commission + fixedSalary; //calculates total of compensation if total sales meet minimum sales
                } else if (totalSales > maximumSales) {
                    compensation = totalSales * commission * advanceRate + fixedSalary; //calculates total compensation if total sales exceed maximum sales
                }

                Double compensationD = new Double(compensation);

                aSales.add(compensationD);

                System.out.println("Current total compensation:" + compensation);

                    for (int i = 0; i < aSales.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(aSales.get(i));
                    System.out.println("Show " + persons.makePerson1() + ".");
                    }
        }
            }

    }
```

I'm sure this is a complete mess of bad coding, but any help would be appreciated, just ignore the random bits of odd coding I put in to try to narrow down what my issue is. Thank you so much.

The rest of the program look like this, I've also removed the bits that were just in for problem testing from previous portions

Main:

```
import java.util.Scanner; //Needed for scanner input
import java.text.DecimalFormat; //Needed for correct output of decimals
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AnnualCompensation {
   private static String Y;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.00"); //This will correctly format the money amounts

    Double totalSales;
    int startY;


    ArrayList<SalesPerson> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<AnnualSales> aSales = new ArrayList<AnnualSales>();

    Scanner start = new Scanner(System.in); //Creates scanner input
    System.out.println("Are you ready to compare sales? Press 1 if yes, 2 if no."); //Prints out entry command
    startY = start.nextInt();

    switch (startY){
    case 1:
        InputClass inputs = new InputClass();
        inputs.getInputs();
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Thank you anyway!");
        System.exit(0);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("You have selected neither Y or N, please try again.");
        System.exit(0);
}


    SalaryTotal calculator = new SalaryTotal(); //Calls class SalaryTotal

    PossibleCompensation table = new PossibleCompensation(); //Calls class PossibleCompensation

}
}
```

Possible Compensation:

```
public class PossibleCompensation {

   SalesPerson persons = new SalesPerson();
   ArrayList<SalesPerson> list = new ArrayList<>();
   ArrayList<AnnualSales> aSales = new ArrayList<AnnualSales>();

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.00"); //This will correctly format the money amounts

double commission; //Variable for the comission
double minimumSales; //Variable to define the minimum amount of annual sales sales persn must make to receive compensation
double maximumSales; //Variable to define the number after which commission increases
double advanceRate; //Variable used to define the rate at which compensation increases after minimum sales are met
double compensation; //Variable for the amount of compensation based on sales
double totalSales; //Variable for sales person annual sale

public void settotalSales(double totalSales) {

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        this.totalSales = totalSales; //Sets the input from AnnualCompensation to totalSales in this class

        commission = .21; //The constant commission rate
        minimumSales = 120000; //The constant minimum sales needed to receive compensation
        maximumSales = 150000; //The constant maximum amount above which commission increases by the advanceRate
        advanceRate = 1.67; //The constant at which compensation increasea after minimum sales
        String heading1 = "Total Sales"; //variable to print a header for the table
        String heading2 = "Total Compensation"; //variable to print a header for the table

        System.out.print("\nBelow is a table based on possible commissions if sales increase:\n"); //Prints instructions
        System.out.printf("\n%20s %20s", heading1, heading2); //prints header and formats spacing

        for (double i=totalSales; i <= (totalSales * 1.5); i+= 5000) { //FOR loop for calculating and constructing table
                if (i < minimumSales) {
                    compensation = 0; //sets compensation to 0 if minimum sales are not met  
                } else if (i <= 150000){
                    compensation = i * commission; //calculates total of compensation if total sales meet minimum sales
                } else if (i > maximumSales) {
                    compensation = i * commission * advanceRate; //calculates total compensation if total sales exceed maximum sales
                }

            System.out.printf("\n%20s %15s", df.format(i), df.format(compensation) + "\n"); //Prints out the table
    }
}
}

class SalesPerson {

String firstName;
String lastName;
String totalSalesStr;

ArrayList<SalesPerson> list = new List<>();
```

SalesPerson class:

```
public SalesPerson() {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.totalSalesStr = totalSalesStr;
}

SalesPerson(String firstName, String lastName, String totalSalesStr) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.totalSalesStr = totalSalesStr;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
}

public String getTotalSalesStr() {
    return this.totalSalesStr;
}

public Double getTotalSales() {
    Double totalSales = Double.parseDouble(totalSalesStr);
    return totalSales;
}

public String makePerson1() {
    String person1 = list.get(0).getFirstName() + " " + list.get(0).getLastName();
    return person1;
}

public String makePerson2() {
    String person2 = list.get(1).getFirstName() + " " + list.get(1).getLastName();
    return person2;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ("Sales person " + this.getFirstName() + " " + this.getLastName() + "  has annual sales of " + this.getTotalSalesStr() + ".");
}

}

class AnnualSales {

Double compensationD;
AnnualSales person1EarningStr;
AnnualSales person2EarningStr;

ArrayList<AnnualSales> aSales = new ArrayList<AnnualSales>();

public AnnualSales() {
    this.compensationD = compensationD;
}

public AnnualSales(Double compensationD) {
    this.compensationD = compensationD;
}

public Double getCompensationD() {
    return this.compensationD;
}

public AnnualSales getperson1EarningStr() {
    person1EarningStr = aSales.get(0);
    return person1EarningStr;
}

public AnnualSales getperson2EarningStr() {
    person2EarningStr = aSales.get(1);
    return person2EarningStr;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ("please show us" + compensationD);
}
}
```

Input class:

```
class InputClass {

String firstName;
String lastName;
Double totalSales;
String totalSalesStr;

CopyOnWriteArrayList<SalesPerson> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

public void getInputs() {
    for(double i=0; i < 2; i++){

        Scanner persFN = new Scanner(System.in); //Creates scanner input
        System.out.println("Enter sales person's first name:"); //Prints out entry command
        String firstName = persFN.next();

        Scanner persLN = new Scanner(System.in); //Creates scanner input
        System.out.println("Enter sales person's last name:"); //Prints out entry command
        String lastName = persLN.next();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Creates scanner input
        System.out.println("Enter Total Sales:"); //Prints out entry command
        totalSales = input.nextDouble();

        String totalSalesStr = totalSales.toString();

        list.add(new SalesPerson(firstName, lastName, totalSalesStr));

        SalaryTotal calculator = new SalaryTotal(); //Calls class SalaryTotal
        calculator.getCompensation(totalSales);

        PossibleCompensation table = new PossibleCompensation(); //Calls class PossibleCompensation
        table.settotalSales(totalSales);

        EarningDifference earning = new EarningDifference();
        earning.settotalSales(totalSales);
    }
}
}
```

I think that should be everything related!

Comment: double totalSalary; //Variable for the total salary ....These comments are unnecessary, you've chosen a good variable name which indicates what value it stores, the comments add to the clutter

Comment: you will have to post SalesPerson, AnnualSales and main class too, as from above code it we are not able to make the flow out of it. Or probably post some other code which will replicate the issue you are getting.

Comment: Most of the commenting is done for the pleasure of my Professor, but I will definitely keep that in mind going forward :)

Comment: Did u run your code in debug mode and can you pin point the line where it is throwing the exception, and what exception is it throwing?

Comment: What's the best method on here to add the rest? Should I answer my own question and post more, or is there another preferred method?

Comment: you should edit your post

Comment: Edited to include everything involved

Comment: I usually get a... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 error, and through testing it looks like nothing I do actually gets saved IN the AnnualSales ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have override `equals()` method in your Classes. As a good practice always make sure you have override both `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Why?

From `Java` [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29).

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list,
>   if it is present. If the list does not contain the element, it is
>   unchanged. More formally, removes the element with the lowest index i
>   such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))) (if such an
>   element exists). Returns true if this list contained the specified
>   element (or equivalently, if this list changed as a result of the
>   call).

If your `ArrayList` element not a `String`(more generally if it is not a inbuilt `Java` class), You need to override `equals()` method.

Comment: Any way I can get an example of what it means? Sadly most the time reading such explanations sound like greek to me, I do better with examples >.<